# Recognizing the user's text-align choise and controlling the text-align display, in a text-area (or text-field) in ReactJS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, text-align

I've build [an app](https://next-f2cee.firebaseapp.com/) that displays many text areas. I personally use the app with two languages - English, and another language which is aligned to the right. By default the text-areas align to the left. If I want to change and align them to the right I can simply press right CTR+Shift. The app is build in React, and when the screen re-renders it is aligned to the left again. I want to somehow control the alignment - recognize if a user chooses to align in a certain way, and save it to the state. How can I recognize how the user chooses to align the text, or if he presses right or left CTR+Shift? And how do I change the text-area so the alignment is controlled?

Answer (score 0):

```
const alignment = ['left', 'right', 'center'];

class Example extends React.component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = { align: 'left' };

    this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this);
  }

  handleKeyDown(e) { // Passes click event to state
    if (e.shiftKey && (e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey)) { // meta key for macbook support
      this.setState({ align: 'right' });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={s.root}>
        <div style={{ textAlign: this.state.align }}> // Sets div text alignment
          <textarea onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown} />
        </div>
      </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a method to control alignment using a button, which is related. But more specifically I'm asking about controlling alignment where there is no click but a Ctr+Shift keyboard button pressed, while the user is in an textArea or textField.

Comment: I misunderstood your question! I edited my original answer to reflect key presses. Hope this is what you were looking for.